# How to discover a password in a binary file

Tags: assembly, passwords, x86-64, reverse-engineering, elf

I received a puzzle recently which has a binary executable and the objective of that puzzle is to discover a password hidden in the hex dump of the binary file. I tried to follow [this guideline](http://manoharvanga.com/hackme/) but I'm out of ideas to continue at the point I've reached. This is the portion of the code which has the logic:

```
#h begins the printf "password: "

4006dc: bf 14 08 40 00          mov    $0x400814,%edi
4006e1: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
#h sets %eax to NULL

4006e6: e8 a5 fe ff ff          callq  400590 <printf@plt>
4006eb: 48 8b 15 6e 09 20 00    mov    0x20096e(%rip),%rdx        # 601060 <stdin@@GLIBC_2.2.5>
4006f2: 48 8d 45 b0             lea    -0x50(%rbp),%rax
#h probably the address of the string "password: "

4006f6: be 32 00 00 00          mov    $0x32,%esi
4006fb: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
4006fe: e8 ad fe ff ff          callq  4005b0 <fgets@plt>
#h calling the fgets function, so here we know which register is being used for storing the input

400703: c7 45 ac 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x54(%rbp)
#h makes mem[rbp-84] = NULL

40070a: c7 45 a8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x58(%rbp)
#h makes mem[rpb-88] = NULL

400711: eb 27                   jmp    40073a <__gmon_start__@plt+0x17a>
#h jumps unconditionally to the pc address 40073a

400713: 8b 45 a8                mov    -0x58(%rbp),%eax
400716: 48 98                   cltq
400718: 0f b6 44 05 b0          movzbl -0x50(%rbp,%rax,1),%eax
40071d: 0f be d0                movsbl %al,%edx
400720: 8b 45 a8                mov    -0x58(%rbp),%eax
400723: 48 98                   cltq
400725: 0f b6 44 05 b0          movzbl -0x50(%rbp,%rax,1),%eax
40072a: 0f be c0                movsbl %al,%eax
40072d: 89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
#h ecx loop counter

40072f: d3 e2                   shl    %cl,%edx
400731: 89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
#h moves edx to eax

400733: 31 45 ac                xor    %eax,-0x54(%rbp)
#h do a xor between eax and -0x54(rbp)

400736: 83 45 a8 01             addl   $0x1,-0x58(%rbp)

#h pc address 40073a is below here
40073a: 8b 45 a8                mov    -0x58(%rbp),%eax
40073d: 48 63 d8                movslq %eax,%rbx
400740: 48 8d 45 b0             lea    -0x50(%rbp),%rax
#h register rax receives the mem[rbp-80] (first local variable)

400744: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
400747: e8 24 fe ff ff          callq  400570 <strlen@plt>
40074c: 48 39 c3                cmp    %rax,%rbx
40074f: 72 c2                   jb     400713 <__gmon_start__@plt+0x153>
#h if %rax < %rdi, jump to pc = 400713

400751: 81 7d ac 62 02 49 0d    cmpl   $0xd490262,-0x54(%rbp)
#here it compares the 0xd490262 memory address with mem[rbp-84], so I guess that the -0x54(%rbp) contains the string we want, but where???

400758: 75 0c                   jne    400766 <__gmon_start__@plt+0x1a6>
#h here it does the jump if not equal, so the contents we want is on $0xd490262

#h WELL DONE!
40075a: bf 1f 08 40 00          mov    $0x40081f,%edi
40075f: e8 fc fd ff ff          callq  400560 <puts@plt>
400764: eb 0a                   jmp    400770 <__gmon_start__@plt+0x1b0>
#h wrong password
400766: bf 2b 08 40 00          mov    $0x40082b,%edi
40076b: e8 f0 fd ff ff          callq  400560 <puts@plt>
400770: 48 8b 4d e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rcx
400774: 64 48 33 0c 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rcx
40077b: 00 00
```

Note: I don't know if my all my comments are correct, so don't trust a 100% at this, please.

So, I'm analyzing this file for 2 days trying to get an idea, but I think I got to a dead end.

Just in case, the binary executes that:

```
$./binary
$password: (fgets function in here)
$wrong password!
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Try to write C code that does the same thing as your assembly code.

Comment: @FUZxxl I already tried to do that, but I think the author of the binary used a completely different logic than me. The hexdump of the binary executable can't get even near :(

Comment: It is very unlikely that C code you write to approximate this code yields the same assembly. The behaviour should match, not the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

since this is some kind of crackme maybe some parts are just decoys, or red herring, so better learn how to use your debugger effectively, like using breakpoints, searching memory address range, etc.

start tracing from the part that gets your string and saves it to the application buffer, trace what instructions are manipulating your input string , find a way how your input is compared with the correct password.

from the looks of it the password is the constant $0xd490262 i guess, since its compared to a value from [rbp-0x54], so if [rbp-0x54] contains $0xd490262 then the jne after the compare will not jump. thereby printing the good boy message.

Comment: when you say "the password is the constant $0xd490262" you mean literally the string "$0xd490262" or the decimal number from it 222888546?

Comment: i mean, the password is a hardcoded value having a hexadecimal value of 0d490262h, so the input value, which came from the user, must end up as that value or has that 4 byte value so it can pass, but those values are not "type-able" characters?, so i'm guessing something is manipulating the input value, its hard to decipher in the disassembly, inspect it in runtime using your debugger to further analyse what is happening.